# How to use htmlspecialchars inside codeigniter html.twig?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, twig

I have a table that display record in a table from database. But it doesn't purify html or record that has javascript or html tags in them. I tried to use htmlspecialchars and doesn't work. Below are the code in twig template.

```
<td class="text-left">{{ Name }}</td> // it is working and displaying data without purifying
```

I'm using htmlspecialchars as follow.

```
<td class="text-left">{{ htmlspecialchars(Name) }}</td>
```

also tried

```
<td class="text-left">htmlspecialchars{{ Name }}</td>
```

Comment: codeigniter or laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use *strip_tags()* instead of *htmlspecialchars()* to purify the html tags.

Comment: thank you for your time on checking on this. I already tried strip_tags and still not working.